# all_tables and dba_segments giving different space occupied by the same tables

Tags: oracle

When I ran the below queries they gave different space occupied by the same table:

```
select bytes/1024/1024 as space, owner
from dba_segments
where segment_name='PARAMETER_STATUS';

     SPACE OWNER
---------- ------------------------------
      4988 FLSTD01
      3124 FLSTD04
      6416 FLSTD02
       808 FLSTD03

select blocks*16/1024,owner
from all_tables
where table_name='PARAMETER_STATUS';

BLOCKS*16/1024 OWNER
-------------- ------------------------------
    4979.39063 FLSTD01
      802.1875 FLSTD03
    6405.98438 FLSTD02
    1966.34375 FLSTD04
```

Why is it giving me different space occupied by the same table?

DB_BLOCK_SIZE=16KB

Comment: Are your stats up to date on that table?

Comment: @Mat yes they are up to date Mat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4097.htm#REFRN23243), `dba_segments.bytes` is the number of bytes used by the database segment. `all_tables.blocks` is the number of blocks **used** inside a table ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286)). Tables don't grow block by block, they grow extent by extent. There is also a third interesting field, `dba_segments.blocks`, which shows how many database blocks are there in a segment.

You can run the following query and see that the number of used blocks in table is generally not the same as the number of blocks in corresponding segments:

```
select s.segment_name, s.blocks segment_blocks, t.blocks table_used_blocks
from dba_segments s
    inner join dba_tables t on s.owner = t.owner and s.segment_name = t.table_name
where t.table_name = 'PARAMETER_STATUS'
```

Also note that due to partitioning, a single table may consist of more than one segment.

Comment: Also, as noted since 11.1 documentation, any storage related column in *_tables view are populated after gathering statistics on the table with the ANALYZE statement or the DBMS_STATS package.  [11.1 Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286)